# how to insert data from one table to another

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT a.nid, a.stock, b.qty, sum( b.qty )
FROM uc_product_stock a
INNER JOIN uc_order_products b ON a.nid = b.nid
GROUP BY a.nid
```

---

the above query give me the following result:

```
nid stock   qty sum(b.qty)
10  746     1   4
11  256     4   11
```

---

now i want to insert this in my custom table. For eg, the structure of custom table is:

```
id | orderIn | orderOut
10  |   746   |   4
11  |   256   |   11
```

---

Iam using this query, but it gives error:

```
insert into custom (id, OrderIn, OrderOut) 
select 
a.nid, 
a.stock,
b.qty,
sum(b.qty)
from 
table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id=b.id
group by a.id
```

Comment: How are `id` and `sku` related? Is sku allways 'sku-'+id ?

Comment: no there is no relation in sku(varchar) and id(int):(

Comment: BTW, I made a mistake in the previous note, and meant is SKU always the string 'prod-' with the id appended.
If there's no relationship, then this query logically can't exist as there's no way to like a specific sku to a particular id.

Comment: @Stuart Moore table 2 i took first was not the right choise. now i had edited the question. Pls have a look

Comment: INSERT into order (sku, orderIn, orderOut)
SELECT a.nid, a.stock, b.qty from uc_product_stock a inner join uc_order_products b on a.nid=b.nid. Whats wrong with the syntax of this mysql query. this query gives error

Comment: here also i want to sum up prod_order for same id i.e for id 1 it would be 20+25=45 and same for id 2 i.e 20+25=45.how can do this/

Comment: What's the created column?

Comment: I think this is too basic for dba.se

Answer (score 1):

You'd use an INSERT..SELECT query like this:

```
insert into custom (sku, OrderIn, OrderOut) 
select 
a.id, 
a.stock,
sum(b.prod_order)
from 
table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id=b.id
group by a.id
```

More details at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

The basic idea is that you build up your select query to define the set of data you want, and then use that as an input to an Insert statement to write it into the table you want to put it in.

In your question you've not defined how the `created` column is generated, so that isn't covered in this query.

Comment: sorry for table 2 structure it does not have sku, instead it is id(i.e a primary key)

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to incorporate your revisions, though please note that as the created column isn't defined anywhere I can't answer that section.

Comment: select 
a.id, 
a.stock,
b.prod_order,
sum(b.prod_order)
from 
table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id=b.id
group by a.id. this is ok. But this - insert into custom (sku, OrderIn, OrderOut) 
select 
a.id, 
a.stock,
b.prod_order,
sum(b.prod_order)
from 
table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id=b.id
group by a.id gives error

Comment: it gives error that there is a syntax error near select

Comment: i had edit my que pls answer that one

Comment: I have edited an an extraneous column that I used for testing. 

Here's a SQLFiddle showing it working - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea8e8

Answer (score 0):

Aashi, you are selecting 4 columns and trying to insert into only 3 columns of another table.